# How to customize FOSUserBundle forms

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have below problem with FOSUserBundle customization.
I was overwritten FOSUser register form, then I changed register_content from

```
{{ form_widget(form) }}
```

to:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
{{ form_label(form.firstname) }}
{{ form_errors(form.firstname) }}
{{ form_widget(form.firstname) }}
{{ form_label(form.lastname) }}
{{ form_errors(form.lastname) }}
{{ form_widget(form.lastname) }}
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
{{ form_label(form.email) }}
{{ form_errors(form.email) }}
{{ form_widget(form.email) }}

{{ form_label(form.plainPassword) }}
{{ form_errors(form.plainPassword) }}
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword) }}

{{ form_label(form.plainPassword.second) }}
{{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.second) }}
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second) }}
</div>
```

But, when I was went to the browser, I got it:
[bad form render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5utM.jpg)

The form renders incorrectly. How I can repair this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this

```
 {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.first) }}
{{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.first) }}
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first) }}

{{ form_label(form.plainPassword.second) }}
{{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.second) }}
{{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second) }}
```

Comment: Ok, this works fine, thank you. I have next question. How I can change the input color when this one will has error? In standard form_widget(form) it has a red color.

Comment: You have two options : overriding CSS of bootstrap, or defining your own form them see this http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

Comment: Thank you very much again, I was wrote this:

<div class="{% if(form_errors(form.plainPassword.first)) %} has-error {% endif %}">
  {{ form_label(form.plainPassword.first) }}
  {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first) }}
  {{ form_errors(form.plainPassword.first) }}
</div>

And this works fine.